# Cohomology Groups from injective resolution

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I know, If *M* is a *G*-module for a injective resolution of *M*, we can define cohomology groups. Can someone give an example to understand, injective resolution and cohomology groups (kernel/image of previous map)

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to understand.

Comment: I want to see a example for , computing cohomology groups via injective resolutions

Comment: Usually one does not compute cohomology using injective resolutions. Examples of computation using projective resolutions are given in all textbooks —have you looked?

Comment: I found one example herehttp://176.58.104.245/ALGANT/EREZ/erez.pdf

Comment: http://176.58.104.245/ALGANT/EREZ/erez.pdf

Comment: page 25, but I am not sure weather resolutin is injective and how they found it